# How to pass variable value from $(document).ready(function() to $(document).on('change','select',function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions.
How can I pass globalcounter variable from "$(document).ready(function()" to "$(document).on('change','select',function()"

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addRow").click(function(){
        var globalcounter = parseFloat(counter);
        counter++;
        $("#theCount").text(counter);
    });
});

$(document).on('change','select',function() {
var data = "";
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url : "<cms:show k_site_link />generate/quotation-ajax.php",
    data: 
        "select_id="+$(this).val(),
        async: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#f_item_detail-' + i + '-product_hsn').val(data.product_details[i].product_hsn);
        $('#f_item_detail-' + i + '-product_price').val(data.product_details[i].product_price);
        $('#f_item_detail-' + i + '-product_tax').val(data.product_details[i].product_tax);
    })
});
```

is this even possible?

I want to use the value of globalcounter at all places in place of "i" in:

```
'#f_item_detail-' + i
```

Comment: So what prevents your from changing `i` to `counter`?

Comment: I want to pass the globalcounter value to the on change function then I will change the "i"

Comment: Have you tried `$('#f_item_detail-' + counter + '-product_hsn')`?

Comment: `var` creates global variable, so you have access to it anywhere in script. Though you can use it instead of `i`.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: Oh it didnt strike me that you were mentioning it this way. Thanks a ton. This solves the issue. I guess I had hit a wall!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the global variable and instead get it from the text variable.

```
let i = parseFloat($("#theCount").text());
$('#f_item_detail-' + i + '-product_hsn').val(data.product_details[i].product_hsn);
$('#f_item_detail-' + i + '-product_price').val(data.product_details[i].product_price);
$('#f_item_detail-' + i + '-product_tax').val(data.product_details[i].product_tax);
```

Similarly, the increment could change too to get rid of global variables.

```
let countText = $("#theCount").text();
if ( !countText )
   $("#theCount").text(1);
else
  $("#theCount").text((parseFloat(countText)+1).toString());
```

Increment Reference: https://jsfiddle.net/0xu2zwnh/